# UnicodeDecodeError При выполнении скрипта

Tags: python, tensorflow

https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py - используя данный скрипт я получаю ошибку - UnicodeDecodeError

скрипт конвертирует файлы из csv в TFRecords для использования в TensorFlow Object Detection API. На вход я даю скрипту файл test.csv и на выходе должен получить test.record

я использую строку `python main.py --csv_input=test.csv  --output_path=test.record` Но получаю ошибку

код ошибки -

File "C:\Users\borislav\Desktop\capchasolver\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 79, in _preread_check
self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 59: invalid continuation byte

В интернете я нашёл решение данной проблемы, где нужно было создать пустой выходной файл, но в моём случае он и так его создаёт (пустой)

Я использую Windows 10, tensorflow 2.5, python 3.9.2 и venv созданный pycharm

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей

Comment: я добавил информации

Comment: А файл наверное в виндовой кодировке cp1251, а не в utf-8? Или в utf-16 ещё может быть.

Comment: Файл был в utf-8, решение я написал ниже в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Решение - надо указать папку с изображениями

```
python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/test_labels.csv --output_path=data/test.record --image_dir=images/test/
```